Sunny Explorer instalation
*Is it possible to install SMA Sunny Explorer (Bluetooth Solar inverter monitor) on Ubantu?
I am new to Ubantu. I downloaded Sunnyexplorer and tried to install.  Couldn't find anything to open it.
Need advice.
